# Creating a description in one column based on another columns number

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a building information table that only contains the building types in numbers (ex: building type = 84). I would like to add another column to the table with the descriptions for each building number type. Something along the lines of where the building type = 84 then set the description type to residential.

Thanks.

[Table being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu9i7.jpg)

Comment: What happens when the type _isn't_ 84?

Comment: Well there are only 27 different building type numbers in the column that I would like to assign a description for.

Comment: Please show sample input and output.  You can't expect someone to answer a question in this state.

Comment: Tim you are right. I have uploaded the table being used.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a lookup table, like so:

```
create table building_types (
  building_type smallint primary key,
  description text not null unique
);
```

Fill it with the required data:

```
insert into building_types values
(84, 'Residential');
```

And do a left outer join against your real table:

```
select
    *
from building_information_table as a
left outer join building_types as b on a.building_type = b.building_type
```